# OpenCL - Access violation reading, not everytime

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a bug I never seen before.

I have a buffer that I want to write on the device (AMD), and I have a **Access violation reading location** error when performing a `queue.finish()`.

And I search around an found nothing, except that if I run my `enqueueReadBuffer()` in blocking mode (CL_TRUE), everything goes fine. But if I just change the flag to `blocking == CL_FALSE` it break with access violation.

Is there something Im missing ? I have been running this pipeline for a while, and nothing wrong with my Nvidia card, only AMD goes crazy with that.

I dont want to force to block the queue just for writting on the device.

Here is my writeBuffer function:

```
void Wrapper::writeBuffer(const cl::Buffer& buffer, const cl_bool blocking,
                                   const size_t sizeData, void * const dataPtr,
                                   cl::Event* ev, const std::vector<cl::Event>& waitList)
{
    cl_int err = ManagerInstance().GetQueue().enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer, blocking, 0, sizeData, dataPtr,
                                                                 ( waitList.size() > 0 ) ? &waitList : NULL,
                                                                 ( ev != NULL ) ? ev : NULL);
    Utils::Function::checkOpenCLError(err, "OCL::Wrapper::writeBuffer - Failed to write buffer on device.");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a small example of what I did wrong, the real code is more complex (an hybrid in between host processing, and device) so it was not obvious since the myPtr can by processed on host, and retransfer during `foo`.

```
cl::Event foo(...) {
    // allocation of the dataPtr.
    std::unique_ptr<Data> myPtr = ...;

    cl::Event evWrite;
    Wrapper::writeBuffer(buffer, CL_FALSE, size, myPtr, &evWrite);
    return evWrite;
}

auto ev = foo();
ev.wait();
```

The issue is that the smart pointer is released before the writeBuffer is done. The ev.wait() should be perform before the return, inside `foo()`.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more code, but since it only happens when blocking is set to false, I would guess that the data is being deallocated before the buffer write actually occurs. Could we see the code calling your `writeBuffer` function, including the object that's being pointed to by `dataPtr`?

Comment: You need to take a look at a bigger picture here. For some reason that synchronization point (blocking) is needed on AMD and it may be that it works without it on NVidia by luck. Other possibility is that you have more kernels and next depended kernel is called too early when blocking is not being used. And so on. We can only guess. More info is needed.

Comment: Its a bit hard to provide more code, since the pipeline is pretty big and complex. But I could try to get put more code, and I will also check for the dataPtr deallocation. But as I said, the problem might also be the driver. This exact pipeline was working in October 2018, and code have not change since that time. I even try with an older revision, and same thing.

Comment: I spend more time on that, and I figure out the problem was about the dataPtr release too early, as suggested by apemanzilla. So as doqtor also point out, I was just lucky that Nvidia transfer is faster than the deallocation... And on CPU device, its always blocking anyway. Sorry for that, but it took me a while to find out the issue.

Comment: @Vuwox You should post an answer talking about how it was early deallocation, and then mark it as accepted in case other people have the same issue in the future